# Rendering internally linked markdown files in pelican

Tags: markdown, pelican

I want to link to various internal markdown documents in a markdown document in pelican. Let's say the markdown document I want to publish as a post is test.md. In test.md I have,

```
[link to markdown1](/md-files/markdown1.md)
```

where md-files directory is in content. But when I serve the blog locally using `make serve`, and click on the link I get the option to download the file. I instead want it to be rendered as a page.

Would it be possible or would I have to convert it to html and then render the html page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case you describe — linking to source content instead of generated output — is precisely why Pelican's [intra-site link syntax](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/content.html#linking-to-internal-content) was introduced. Using the example you provided, the relevant link syntax would be:

```
[link to markdown1]({filename}/md-files/markdown1.md)
```